# Android RelativeLayout alinhar itens

Tags: android, android-layout

Não estou conseguindo alinhar verticalmente pelo centro os itens da terceira linha assinalados na imagem. Trata-se de um layout de itens de uma listView.

Já tentei gravity="center", layout_gravity="center", layout_centerVertical="true".

Não gostaria de usar um LinearLayout para agrupar os itens, alguma idéia ?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:padding="5dp">

    <TextView
        style="@style/textBase"
        android:id="@+id/labNom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Nome da categoria"/>

    <TextView
        style="@style/textNote"
        android:id="@+id/labDes"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/labNom"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:text="Descrição longa da categoria"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/labDes"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_thumb_up"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lab1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/labDes"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/img1"
        android:text="57"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Qual é a dimensão da imagem(mdpi)?

Comment: 32x32. Mas o emulador está usando 36x36 (Nexus S hdpi). Ooops! pode ser isso.

Comment: Arrumei a resolução das imagens, 24x24 - 36x36 - 48x48 e 72x72. Sem resultado.

Comment: A imagem pode ser maior que o texto se assim for não as consegue alinhar sem usar padding ou margin. Experimente assim: retire `android:layout_below="@id/labDes"` do último textView e acrescente `android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/img1"`. A imagem e o texto deverão ficar alinhados por baixo, se os centros não alinharem é porque têm alturas diferentes.

Answer (score 1):

Coloca sua `ImageView` e o `TextView` dentro de um `LinearLayout` com `gravity=center` e fica tudo certo, desta forma:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/labDes"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lab1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/img1"
            android:text="57"
            />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/labDes"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_thumb_up"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Boa Sorte!

Comment: Conforme citado na pergunta eu não gostaria de usar um LinearLayout para agrupar os itens. De qualquer forma obrigado.